# Faster two way Boomark/History Sync for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, sync, bookmarks, performance, history

I need a fast automatic two-way bookmark & history sync.

Firefox sync seems too slow because I might bookmark/visit a URL then within a few mins put desktop to sleep and leave the house; if it hasn't synced, then I don't have a way of getting it on my laptop (or vice versa). My home upload is only around 200kbps so maybe that's why FF sync seems slow? (I mean it's minutes, not seconds slow).

I have read there are a few ways like xmarks/delicious/google but I don't want clutter like extra toolbars or have to visit a site to get bookmarks, they should be as native in the Firefox bookmarks bar as possible, organised in the folders/tags.

I know someone must have experimented/know more about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Install [Xmarks](https://www.xmarks.com/). It does a pure native sync. The bookmark handler will still be Firefox. You'll add bookmarks using Firefox & you'll access/manage bookmarks -again- using Firefox. You'll never need to visit its website unless you are on a third-party PC where you need your bookmarks.

It features toolbar button but not for accessing/adding bookmarks. Its for sync etc which you can hide after setting auto-sync.

In fact, you'll never feel that you are using an add-on over your bookmarks!

And yes, it supports History sync too.. the same way as of Bookmark sync.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the interval in which FF is calling the sync action. This should dramatically speed up the whole thing. You should be able to set it to 5 minutes if you want, but I cannot say what that does to your internet connection.

Here is an instruction how to do it:

http://tomtsui.wordpress.com/2011/04/29/modify-firefox-sync-interval/

Also, you can add a "sync" button to your browser bar so you can sync manually just in case you changed bookmarks seconds before closing down the computer.